# How to get ER diagram for an existing database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, erd

I have a database in `MySQL` and want to generate its `ER diagram`.How can it be done? Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [MYSQL WORKBENCH](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: +1 Using this for ages but never saw that graphical awsomeness :)